# Workflow foundation hosting - console, windows service, asp.net

Tags: asp.net, windows-services, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I read some blog that If we host workflow foundation in asp.net, there will be issues with workflow persistence, is this correct? and what is the better idea to host workflow foundation on asp.net or on windows service?

Please Help.

Thanks/Yogesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are talking about Workflow Foundation 4 the best hosting solution is probably [Windows Server AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849) (extension to IIS and WAS) where workflows are exposed as WCF services.